# Select Option Css

Tags: html, css, tooltip, html-select

I have a simple dropdown select option - example below

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" title="NEED THIS BIGGER AND FORMATED" >Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

When hover over Volvo a type of ToolTip pops up - but would like it larger and appear quicker.

Is there a solution to this - maybe css.

Comment: It is very bothersome to style `select` tags. You can also use a div/ul/whatever instead. These are easy to style. Here are some examples of styled select tags: https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is exactly what you want, but it is a step in that direction. As @Evochrome mentioned, it's difficult to style native `select` elements. Styling the `title` attribute on top of that is even more difficult.

In order to style the `select` element you need to add a `size` attribute. This creates a potentially undesired effect of turning the `select` into a list instead of a dropdown. Unfortunately this is required.

From there we can style the `title` by creating an `:after` pseudo-element with the `content` set to the `title` attribute, using the `option[title]:hover:after` selector. This allows you some options for styling the title attribute but you're still limited.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
}

option[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 110px;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: italic;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>
<select size="4">
  <option value="volvo" title="NEED THIS BIGGER AND FORMATED" ><a>Volvo</a></option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for - but does not seem to work when in css file - although working fine here.

Comment: Shouldn't matter if it's in a CSS file. The styles might be getting overruled.

Comment: The title css from the option is in to right of the screen, not next to the options.

Comment: You might need to wrap the `select` in a `div` and give it a `position: relative`.